# How do I allow the user to select from the list to make a call

Tags: android, android-listview, call

```
String [] AgricultureNumbers ={
        "Administration           347-648-2999 ",
        "Legal office             347-895-3456",
        "Permanent Secatery       347-852-6665"
};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AgricultureNumbers);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "347-648-2999"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I want the user to call the item selected number, but it only call the 347-648-2999..Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It gives me an error, and it still makes the call before showing the list. What I really want to happen is the list is shown, then the user taps on the person he wants to call. So if he want to call legal office he taps on the number, if he want to call admin, he taps on admin and so on.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have a typo with a colon instead of a double quote at the end of line 4. Is that the actual code?

Comment: If you got an error, then post the details of the error that you got! Stack traces, in particular, often show exactly where a problem is. Feel free to edit your question with the link underneath it.

Comment: You're starting the intent right after setting your adapter, which causes it to jump to the intent immediately. If you want to happen after onclick, then use OnItemSelected listener for your list.